# How can I perform recursive methods with generic class

Tags: swift, generics, recursion, types

I have a class that has one function that does multiplication without using build-in methods. I got my function to work without using a generic, but I can get it to work while using a generic. My problem is my recursive call-back function is giving me an error each time I try and call it. Any feedback?

my error is : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7bc42af70)

```
class Math5<T: Numeric> {
    func multiplier(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> T {
        if a == 0 || b == 0 {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return a + multiplier(a, b - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full text of error message you're getting so we can best help you.

Comment: @ItaiFerber my error is Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7bc42af70)

Comment: The code you posted works fine for simple cases. I tested with `XCTAssertEqual(Math5().multiplier(3, 4), 12)`. Show us how you're actually calling it and what arguments you're passing that make it crash.

Comment: Your code will eventually crash with a stack overflow if you call it with a very large `b`, a negative `b`, or a `b` with a fractional part (like `1.1`). Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @robmayoff I guess my error is coming trying to evaluate a Double and Int. I expected since both a and b were of type T I could compare both and return the output as here:                                                                                                  
 var m = Math5()
    print(m.multiplier(150, 0.65))

Comment: `var m = Math5()` will not compile, because the compiler doesn't know what concrete type to use for `T`. The error is “Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your multiplication algorithm is only valid if `b` is a non-negative integer. If `b` is negative, or includes a fraction, then `b == 0` will never become true. If you at least constrain type `T` to `UnsignedInteger`, then the compiler enforces those limitations at compile-time:

```
class Math5<T: UnsignedInteger> {
```

You can generalize so that the first argument can be any `AdditiveArithmetic` while only allowing an `UnsignedInteger` for the second argument. Let's drop the `class` and use a free function:

```
func multiply<LHS: AdditiveArithmetic, RHS: UnsignedInteger>(
    _ lhs: LHS,
    _ rhs: RHS
) -> LHS {
    guard lhs != .zero && rhs != 0 else { return .zero }
    return lhs + multiply(lhs, rhs - 1)
}

multiply(2.5, 3 as UInt) // result: 7.5
```

You can still crash with a stack overflow if you pass in a large enough value for `b`. Since Swift doesn't guarantee tail call elimination, you should also change your algorithm to use a loop instead of recursion if you want to avoid stack overflows.

```
func multiply<LHS: AdditiveArithmetic, RHS: UnsignedInteger>(
    _ lhs: LHS,
    _ rhs: RHS
) -> LHS {
    guard lhs != .zero else { return .zero }
    var answer: LHS = .zero
    var rhs = rhs
    while rhs > 0 {
        answer += lhs
        rhs -= 1
    }
    return answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the function generic

```
func multiplier<T: Numeric>(_ a:T, _ b:T) -> T {
 if a == 0 || b == 0 {
  return 0
 }
 return a+multiplier(a,b-1)
}
```

Same implementation

Comment: I tried this implementation and I received the same error.

Comment: Interesting, it works for me just fine. In anyway the solution proposed above are more efficient. Thought you were looking for a specific implementation